# Regex to validate numbers and forward slashes

Tags: regex

How do I validate the following:

`xxxx/xx/xxxx`

Where x is a real number. No optionals.

**edit**: i meant natural, not real. i expected the question to be closed so i wasn't thorough. will try some solutions now, much appreciated

Comment: What language are you using? You're not providing a lot of context here.

Comment: and what is the format of a _real number_ for you?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$
```

`\d` is a digit (assuming you mean this with "real number")

`^` is the start of the string

`$` is the end of the string

The anchors `^` and `$` are important otherwise it will verify a string as OK with other stuff before or after.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it `/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean signed float or double by "real number" with point [.] decimal delimiter:

```
[0-9.-]{4}/[0-9.-]{2}/[0-9.-]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

`^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{4}$`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to do this

^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$

Reference by : http://www.regexlib.com/%28A%28eR6Gkqvpo-OLdDvZuzrzJABJYX9SqBZ9FRcri31SaQu-qCbGBQpcLfGRVS1KfzA2yaDkW3a3lWOnVPw03BEyNTIugHDvCcG39B0Uq_xP9Wd1geTL6RmKw0WBT7ufdIO54MZegiqrg6g_53DWBl7JQ4E2GCdlMnUmCz1eN4JKvwBMDI76kW4DulBjeo2kJbyH0%29%29/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=17

Gaurav Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language you are using.

```
^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

You need a `/` at the start and the end of the pattern in most languages.

Some languages allow other separators, in that case you don't have to escape the `/`: `x^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9]...x`

Some languages allow specifying a count for matching in which case it's going to be `/^[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/`

And some languages allow using \d , in that case it's even simpler, check the answer of @stema